# Vue3 create component dynamically

Tags: vuejs3

I try to create a component using defineComponent().  It is strange that "HelloWord" showups correctly using import but "HelloWord2" doesn't show using defineComponent function.

```
<template>
  <HelloWorld />
  <HelloWorld2 />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'

const HelloWorld2 = defineComponent({
  template: `<div>Hello World 2</div> <v-text-field label="Label"></v-text-field>`,
});

</script>
```

Thanks
Wilson

Comment: This code should work. Try it out by creating a new Vue app to eliminate any other influencing factors.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I am using Vite4 and Vue3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime compilation is not included in the default (e.g: `global`) Vue export, because in most cases it's not necessary.

If you need runtime compilation, use the `vue.esm-browser(.min).js` build (instead of the `vue.global(.min).js` one).

Comment: Hi Tao,  
Thanks for your information.  Base on your information, I found [How to enable runtime template compiler?][1] which solved the problem. But it doesn't work with Vuetify.
```
<template>
  <HelloWorld />
  <HelloWorld2 />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'

const HelloWorld2 = defineComponent({
  template: `<div>Hello World 2</div> v-text-field label="Label"></v-text-field>`,
});

</script>
```
Any idea?  
Thanks
Wilson
  [1]: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/4158

Answer (score 1):

1. Tao's answer is correct.
2. For Vuetify component, it needs to import Vuetify controls manually (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/)

Thanks Tao again.

Wilson